# Generics and subtyping

Tags: java, generics

> Create a class with a generic type `T`. A subclass of the class that defines a second type parameter, called `V`. Call the methods from both classes using the object. Create 2 objects with different objects

This is the question.

This is not homework if anyone might think. I am doing some java papers for practice. I don't understand how to "create 2 objects with different objects". Can anyone help?

```
class Gen<T> 
 {
  T obj;
  Gen(T ob)
  {
    obj = ob;
  }

 T getobj()
  {
    return obj;
  }
}

class Gen2<T, V> extends Gen<T>
{
  V obj1;
  Gen2(T ob,V ob1)
   {
    super(ob);
    obj1 = ob1;
   }

 V getobj1()
 { 
    return obj1;
 }

}

public class Ch2Lu4Ex3 
 {
  public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      Gen2<String,String> g = new Gen2<String,String>("robin","raj");        

      System.out.println(g.getobj1());
      System.out.println(g.getobj());
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here.  Why can't you just supply different generic parameters?

Comment: Well I did everything the question asked for but the last line is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do things like:

```
Gen<Integer> gen1 = new Gen<Integer>(10);
Gen2<Integer> gen2 = new Gen2<Integer,String>(10,"Hello");
```

Or you could combine them since they are on the same hierarchy.

```
Gen<Integer> gen1 = new Gen2<Integer,String>(10,"Hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

The last part of the question:

> Create 2 objects with different objects

```
Gen2<Integer,String> inst = new Gen2<Integer,String>(1, "robin");
```

Comment: @Robin 
you are basically passing two different abject types as generic type arguments(one is an Integer and another is a String)

Comment: @Robin Yeah, the quoted question is worded very poorly. "Generic type arguments" is a better phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for something like:

```
Gen2<String,String> g = new Gen2<String,String>("robin","raj");
Gen2<Integer,Integer> h = new Gen2<Integer,Integer>(1, 2);
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Both `g` and `h` are instances of `Gen2`, however they are using different generic types. For the `g` instance, the `T` and `V` types have type `String`. In contrast, both `T` and `V` are of type `Integer` for `h`.